# Change summary graph in Task Manager?

Tags: windows-10, task-manager

Lately I have been using my computers for Folding@Home. I enjoy having the task manager graphs on the screen showing utilization. However for my GPU, the utilization shown in the preview is the 3D utilization which is 0 for folding. Is there anyway to change the preview graph to show the Compute 1 graph instead?

[image: Screenshot of task manager with the preview graph for GPU 0 showing no usage but the Compute 1 graph showing 90% utilization]

Comment: You can right click on the Graph and change to Summary View. That makes it much simpler and possibly more meaniful.